# function using a list in python

Tags: python, list, function

I want a function to return me the value of the equation for every number in the list. I have a list of 24 parameters, and I need to solve an equation for every value of this list.

This is the way I get my list:

```
wlist=[]

def w(i):

    for i in range(24):
        Calctruesolar=((i*60/1440)*1440+eq_time()+4*long-60*timezone)%1440
        if Calctruesolar/4<0:
            Calcw=(Calctruesolar/4)+180
            wlist.append(Calcw)
            print(Calcw)
        else:
            Calcw=(Calctruesolar/4)-180
            wlist.append(Calcw)
            print(Calcw)
```

Then, the list is this one:

```
>>> wlist=
[166.24797550450222, -178.75202449549778, -163.75202449549778, -148.75202449549778, -133.75202449549778, -118.75202449549778, -103.75202449549778, -88.75202449549778, -73.75202449549778, -58.75202449549778, -43.75202449549778, -28.75202449549778, -13.752024495497778, 1.2479755045022216, 16.24797550450222, 31.24797550450222, 46.24797550450222, 61.24797550450222, 76.24797550450222, 91.24797550450222, 106.24797550450222, 121.24797550450222, 136.24797550450222, 151.24797550450222]
```

Now, I use the next function:

```
def hourly_radiation(wlist):

    for i in wlist:
        Calcrt=(math.pi/24)*(a()+b()*math.cos(math.radians(i)))*((math.cos(math.radians(i)))-math.cos(math.radians(wss())))/(math.sin(math.radians(wss()))-((math.pi*wss()/180)*math.cos(math.radians(wss()))))
        CalcI=Calcrt*radiation
        print(Calcrt,CalcI)
```

So, I want to receive `Calcrt` and `CalcI` for every value inside the list. But it doesn't work. I have been looking for information in internet and tutorials but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Describe how it doens't work.

Comment: Why don't you create the list inside the function and put a `return wlist` at the end? You could also have only a function that solves one equation and call it inside a list-comprehension: `[w(el) for el in data]`.

Comment: I don't receive any error. When I input hourly_radiation(wlist) I don't receive anything, the program doesn't work, like if this function wouldn't exist.

Comment: @user2882337 Probably because `wlist` is empty. You *did* call `w(i)` before `hourly_radiation` right?

Comment: Take a look at the PEP8 style guide

Comment: What are `a()` and `b()`?

Comment: btw the `i` parameter in the w() method is not actually used, being masked by the `for i in` loop.

Comment: Bakuriu you are right! What a stupid error! I didn't call w(i) before hourly_radiation and because of this wlist was empty...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def hourly_radiation(wlist):
    rt_list = []
    I_list = []
    for i in wlist:
        Calcrt = (math.pi/24)*(a()+b()*math.cos(math.radians(i)))*((math.cos(math.radians(i)))-math.cos(math.radians(wss())))/(math.sin(math.radians(wss()))-((math.pi*wss()/180)*math.cos(math.radians(wss()))))
        CalcI = Calcrt*radiation
        rt_list.append(Calcrt)
        i_list.append(CalcI)
        print(Calcrt,CalcI)
    dict = {}
    dict["Calcrt"] = rt_list
    dict["CalcI"] = i_list
    return dict
```

This would return the values as a dictionary containing two lists. You may use any data structure that matches your requirements.

You may also create a tuple in each loop run and append it to a list and return it, like:

```
def hourly_radiation(wlist):
    rt_list = []
    data = ()
    for i in wlist:
        Calcrt = (math.pi/24)*(a()+b()*math.cos(math.radians(i)))*((math.cos(math.radians(i)))-math.cos(math.radians(wss())))/(math.sin(math.radians(wss()))-((math.pi*wss()/180)*math.cos(math.radians(wss()))))
        CalcI = Calcrt*radiation
        data = (Calcrt, CalcI)
        print(Calcrt, CalcI)
        rt_list.append(data)
    return rt_list
```

> I have not run or tested this code, but I hope it should work.
>
> Please use this as a starting point and not as a copy-paste solution.

Comment: It's working! Thank you very much theghostofc! I realize what my error was, I needed to call w(i) to create the list (wlist) before trying to get the value of hourly_radiation(wlist), because the if I don't operate in this way the wlist is empty. Thank you!